# Remove key pair on ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 instance running Ubuntu. I set it up with a key pair to authenticate, but now I want password authentication. How do I remove the key pair and replace it with a password?

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended to use a key to access your instance. But if you really want to do it. This is how:

- Go to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Look for `PasswordAuthentication no` and change it to `PasswordAuthentication yes`
- Restart your SSH server `sudo service ssh start`

If you want to disable key authentication, change `PubkeyAuthentication yes`
 to `PubkeyAuthentication no`